# Google charts not showing all bars configured

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using google charts and i'm trying to show 'Negotiation' bar as you can see in the code, although I inserted it in the array and it doesn't appear in the graph:

What am I missing here?

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});   
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Negotiation',' Creativity ',' People Management ',' Coordination with Others ',' Orientation to serve ',' Emotional Intelligence ',' Complex Problem Solving ',' Cognitive Flexibility ',' Critical Thinking ',' Taking of Decisions'],
                    ['Líder ',      3, 2, 5,   1 ,3.2, 3.3, 3.1,2.4 ,2.5 ],
                    ['Colaborador', 2, 3, 2.5, 5 ,2.2, 5.1 ,3.6,2.1 ,3 ], 
                ]);
                var options = {
                    title : 'Talento bahia',
                    legend: {position: 'right', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 11}},
                    vAxis: {title: 'Pontuação'},
                    seriesType: 'bars',
                    series: {
                        0: { color: '#631E80' },
                        1: { color: '#FCE22B' },
                        2: { color: '#4A308B' },
                        3: { color: '#011F9B' },
                        4: { color: '#C81212' },
                        5: { color: '#AF3423' },
                        6: { color: '#247D4B' },
                        7: { color: '#23B634' },
                        8: { color: '#5EC4FF' },
                        9: { color: '#F15757' }
                    }
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('container'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container" style = "width: 990px; height: 400px; margin: 0 0 -100px 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: You want to show ten bars, but whats the bar missing? Whats the description and the value you expect? it isnt clear....
 
And your code looks good because 'Líder' and 'Colaborador' has 9 values.

Comment: hello @LuisPauloPinto! I hope to create a bar for Negotiation, as you can see in the code, although I inserted it in the array it doesn't appear in the graph

Comment: in your array definition, `'Negotiation'` is the column heading for the x-axis values. you need to re-name `'Negotiation'` to something else add another value column for `'Negotiation'`...

Answer (score 1):

you are missing some data...

the first element on bar names arrays its like the specification of the array:

```
 ['LABELS', 'Negotiation',' Creativity ',' People Management ',' Coordination with Others ',' Orientation to serve ',' Emotional Intelligence ',' Complex Problem Solving ',' Cognitive Flexibility ',' Critical Thinking ',' Taking of Decisions']
```

And your 2 arrays of data values has only 9 values each..
in the example i add one more value => 15

```
['Líder ',      15, 3, 2, 5,   1 ,3.2, 3.3, 3.1,2.4 ,2.5 ],
['Colaborador', 15, 2, 3, 2.5, 5 ,2.2, 5.1 ,3.6,2.1 ,3 ],
```

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});   
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['LABELS', 'Negotiation',' Creativity ',' People Management ',' Coordination with Others ',' Orientation to serve ',' Emotional Intelligence ',' Complex Problem Solving ',' Cognitive Flexibility ',' Critical Thinking ',' Taking of Decisions'],
                    ['Líder ',      15, 3, 2, 5,   1 ,3.2, 3.3, 3.1,2.4 ,2.5 ],
                    ['Colaborador', 15, 2, 3, 2.5, 5 ,2.2, 5.1 ,3.6,2.1 ,3 ], 
                ]);
                var options = {
                    title : 'Talento bahia',
                    legend: {position: 'right', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 11}},
                    vAxis: {title: 'Pontuação'},
                    seriesType: 'bars',
                    series: {
                        0: { color: '#631E80' },
                        1: { color: '#FCE22B' },
                        2: { color: '#4A308B' },
                        3: { color: '#011F9B' },
                        4: { color: '#C81212' },
                        5: { color: '#AF3423' },
                        6: { color: '#247D4B' },
                        7: { color: '#23B634' },
                        8: { color: '#5EC4FF' },
                        9: { color: '#F15757' }
                    }
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('container'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container" style = "width: 990px; height: 400px; margin: 0 0 -100px 0 auto"></div>
```